# Do link tags with media queries that resolve to false still get downloaded?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Given the following link tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="xlarge.css" media="max-width: 70em" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="large.css" media="max-width: 60em" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="medium.css" media="max-width: 50em" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="small.css" media="max-width: 40em" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="xsmall.css" media="max-width: 30em" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="retina.css" media="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

On initial load, are all six of these stylesheets downloaded, or just those that media queries have resolved to true? For instance, if I was on a retina-capable browser that calculated out to the medium breakpoint, would it only result in four http requests?

Comment: The first five are all invalid media queries... the surrounding `()` must be there since `max-width` is a media feature within an expression, not a media type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the stylesheets will get downloaded regardless of whether the media queries evaluate to true or false. Even the first five media queries you have, which are all invalid because of missing parentheses around the `max-width` expressions, won't prevent those stylesheets from being requested by the browser. (Invalid media queries simply resolve to false automatically.)

In CSS, media queries only control whether or not the CSS rules in those stylesheets are applied to your page, not whether or not the stylesheets themselves get requested.

Comment: For this reason, would a JavaScript approach of determining screen size/browser versions and then loading the appropriate CSS files be preferable, or are the costs of JS more than the costs of loading unneeded CSS files? In your 141k rep opinion :)

Comment: I'm only turning 21 next week, but [one of this year's 24ways articles](http://24ways.org/2012/responsive-responsive-design) discusses that as a solution, with a link to [eCSSential](https://github.com/filamentgroup/eCSSential) which provides this very functionality (albeit optimized for mobile-first designs). That said I think it might be worth investing in a script, especially since stylesheets can eventually get large.